# 1.5 hour layover long enough?

Tags: air-travel, germany, airport-transfer

I'm going to be traveling to Germany from the US, and on the flight back that is preferable for other reasons, we'll be going Nuremberg->Frankfurt, then have 1.5 hours, then -> Chicago.

Is that long enough for that stage?  I'm not an experienced international traveller (I've never been on that side of the Atlantic, for example), and I'm somewhat concerned about what might happen if my puddle-jumper gets delayed (as I'm sure they do from time to time).

(Unfortunately, the other option is a 5 hour layover; that seems to me to be just short enough that we can't really go see anything (not that FRA has much to see from what I've read) and long enough my two toddlers will dislike it if we stay at the airport.)

Comment: Additionally, before anyone posts 'Take a train to Frankfurt', I'd love to do that - but the tickets are cheaper to Nuremberg than to Frankfurt, even on the same exact flight.  Wonders of airline pricing systems...

Comment: 90 minutes is plenty in FRA.  I did a similar transfer a few days ago, and could have made it in under 30 if I had to.

Comment: Does it matter that it is international, or is that irrelevant as long as the arriving flight is domestic?  (I know to allow hours for customs in case of delays when arriving.)

Comment: The linked question basically answers this and gives links to the airport website which will help. They key question is whether you've booked on a single ticket -- if so then the system has already decided you can make the connection and if there are issues you'll be rebooked. If the two flights are separate tickets then you're on your own and will run into issues if the first is delayed. But as @Doc says 90 minutes is plenty, and there are 'fast lanes' for passport control and security if you're running late (and you will have to go through immigration, etc as it's an international flight).